# Dynamic script generation and output issues

Tags: javascript

On my page I need to make a dynamic script with `src=some_external_path` element.
That script element donwloads some JS inside of itself and that JS intern needs to be executed in order to pull some image content.

My problem is that it needs some time to complete JS execution inside that script element, how is it achievable?

It works if I insert alert by the end of the script or run some awkward `for` loop, unfortunately it doesn't work with `setTimeOut` function.

Here is sample code:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute("src", "some_external_path");
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(s);

// if i replace that alert - doesn't work, it seems page needs some delay
alert(document.getElementById('test').text);
```

I also tried something like:

```
setTimeout(function(scriptElement){
    document.getElementById('test').appendChild(scriptElement);
}, 5000, s);
```

And it didn't work either, I also have thought of executing code inside that script element but it doesn't seem to work because of security restrictions(script.text or script.innerHTML return blank string);

Can you suggest anything to make this code complete transaction without loops and hopefully self-made delays ?

Comment: put alerts after your each line and give them 1,2,3 like, ---alert("1");2.line code ------ alert("2") and so on. Check if there is smth wrong in the execute order.

Comment: and ? thats what i did, look at the code - it works but its unacceptable in my situation

Comment: Could you explain this again. It doesn't entirely make sense. It sounds like you are trying to do some JSONP-like functionality.

Comment: no i didnt just say put some alert or smth to make it work, your codes may be executed in wrong order for example append child may work before setting the attribute. Check it then lets think about other possible problems.

Comment: Can't you just move your logic into a function to be called by the script itself? That's the easiest way to ensure execution continues only when the script is loaded.

Comment: i threw some alerts, code executes as i've written above, it just needs some time after append string.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

If you do not want to use jQuery, just look it up how it is done and inspire from it.

Comment: unfortunately this function is just a wrapper for ajax call, but i need to grab those scripts from domain that differs from my.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (without using jQuery when you don't need to):

```
var loadScript = function(url, cb){
  var s = document.createElement("script"), done = false;
  s.setAttribute("src", url);
  s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function(){
  if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
     done = true;
     cb();
    }
  };
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

And you call it like so:

```
loadScript("http://path.to.my/script.js", function(){
  alert("YAY its loaded");
});
```

I hope that helps.